# underscore how to use omit

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How does underscore's omit work. I was expecting to remove properties with key 1 and 2 below. but it is not.

http://jsfiddle.net/FMaDq/1/

```
var test = {
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [],
    4: []
}

var out = _.omit(test, [1,2])
var out2 = _.omit(test, 1,2)
console.log(out)
console.log(out2)

Object {1: Array[0], 2: Array[0], 3: Array[0], 4: Array[0]}
Object {1: Array[0], 2: Array[0], 3: Array[0], 4: Array[0]}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`_omit` calls `_contains` which includes this line of code:

```
return value === target;
```

The keys will be strings, so you need to pass strings in to compare to (since `"1" === 1` is false).

```
_.omit(test, "1", "2")
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess key needs to be string. This worked.
http://jsfiddle.net/FMaDq/2/

```
var out = _.omit(test, ['1','2'])
```